# Clickonce: applicationUri is null with Allow URL parameters to be passed set to true

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a winforms application deployed via clickonce and would like to harvest querystring arguments for the purpose of sending clickable links with parameters. I have tried using ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData, but neither of these return query strings. In Visual Studio (or set through MageUI), "Allow URL parameters to be passed to application" is set to true and this setting is carried in the deployment manifest.

Am i missing an additional setting to allow querystring parameters to be passed to the application?

Note: I am calling the deployed application through windows explorer or IE with URIs such as : file:C:\Users\\Deploy\TestApp.application?testarg123. Could this be causing problems?

Thanks

```
static void Main(){
...
Uri activationData = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri;
                    MessageBox.Show(activationData.ToString());
...
}
```

Comment: it's only available  through network deployment like http, you can check the property ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed if it true

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation on the ApplicationDeployment.ActivationUri Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri?view=netframework-4.8), setting the `TrustUrlParameters = true` and using a full URL (not UNC path) to launch the program should allow access to the query string parameters.

**Try making the file path a URL, setting a value for your query parameter, and use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to access the value. Example:**

URL to launch the application

```
file:///C:\Users\\Deploy\TestApp.application?testarg=123
```

Method to retrieve the query string parameters

```
private NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters()
{
    NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();

    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
        nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    }

    return (nameValueTable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I have updated my code to use this method to retrieve the querystring but still no data... If i use ` activationData = String.Join(" ,",GetQueryStringParameters().AllKeys);
            MessageBox.Show(activationData);` to retrieve information, the returned data is empty

Comment: What is the URL used to open the program? Have you also set `TrustUrlParameters = true`?

Comment: I am using file:///C:\Users\..\Deploy\Test.application?testarg=123 to launch. As for TrustUrlParameters, I have the appropriate box checked in visual studio (Properties>Publish>Options>Allow URL parameters to be passed to application). The deployed .application manifest also has the line ` <deployment install="true" trustURLParameters="true" /> `. Is there anywhere else this needs to be set?